Как отобразить информацию одного поля entry tkinter в другом поле entry
Сейчас создаю небольшую програмку для расчета.
Проблема вот в чем: есть два поля entry. Нужно ввести число в первое поле, при этом во втором поле должно появиться это число умноженное на 12%.
Как сделать это через нажатие на кнопку, я вполне себе представляю, а вот как сделать так чтобы число умноженное на 12% сразу появилось во втором поле, не могу сообразить.
Может кто подскажет легкий пример или скинет ссылку где посмотреть соответствующий пример?

Связанный ответ.
Вот хорошая статья, обратите внимание на пример Отслеживание изменения переменной - trace_add()
И небольшой пример:
import tkinter as tk

def auto_update(*args):
    try:
        value = float(entry1.get())
        result = value * 0.12
        str2_var.set(f"{result:.2f}")
    except ValueError:
        str2_var.set("")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("auto_update")

str1_var = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=str1_var)
entry1.pack()

str2_var = tk.StringVar()
entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=str2_var, state="readonly")
entry2.pack()

str1_var.trace_add("write", auto_update)

root.mainloop()


Я думаю, вы имеете в виду это:
...


# функция-хэндлер
def on_entry1_change(*args):
  global entry_var, entry2
  try:
    # вставляем
    entry2.insert(0, str(float(entry_var.get() * 0.12))
  except TypeError:
    # если entry1 не число
    ...


# StringVar для хранения текста Entry
entry_var = tk.StringVar()


# привязка хэндлера к StringVar
entry_var.trace("w", on_entry1_change)

# создание Entry с аргументом — наша переменная
entry1 = tk.Entry(textvariable = entry_var)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry()
entry2.pack()

EDIT: лет 100 не писал на питоне — если есть ошибки, поправьте
